# How do you call the entity that will have duplicates assigned to?

Tags: terminology

I'm looking for the best word to use describing the entity that will have a duplicate or duplicates associated with, the one that will remain, say, during a merging process, while the duplicate of it will be removed (be archived / hidden... etc).

Here are the possibilities:

1. **Master** - I saw / heard this one being used the most, someone told me it's sexist / politically incorrect as it is referring to a male
2. **Main** - Not sure if it's the best for my use-case, but might be another good choice in my eyes
3. **Original** - Although this one assumes the creator of the duplicate was aware of the existence of the "Original"...?
4. **Parent** - I don't think of this as a parent child relationship, it's more like twins, then again someone told me twins "are born at the same time"

**EDIT**: I'm not looking for an academic's answer, I'm looking for a best practice in an app, eg. what would users of an app react the best to / feel being the most intuitive to use / see the easiest to understand / think of it as the most accurate description of the function / feature they're are looking for when they're associating / merging duplicates.

Comment: This is probably a better question Stack English Language and Usage. Unless this is somehow specific to UX?

Comment: @TimGrant I think it is because I'm trying to use it in an app that people will interact with... unless I'm misunderstanding the purpose of UX...

Comment: Can you please elaborate more on what you mean or put in meaningful examples? I don't really understand you question

Comment: @piegames I have updated the title and the first sentence of the description; hope it makes it clearer.

Comment: @webeno, you are looking for the best word with a particular meaning. How would the fact that you mean to put that word into a UI affect what the correct word would be? (I don't see how it would.)

Comment: @TimGrant I'm not looking for an academic's answer, I'm looking for a best practice in an app... eg. what would users of an app react the best to / feel being the most intuitive to use / see the easiest to understand / think of it as the most accurate description of the function / feature they're are looking for when they're associating / merging duplicates. The more I write about this, the more I think it's very much of a UX question...

Comment: OK then, you probably want to put that justification into your question.

Comment: I'd go with **master**, it's the most common and known way, so no need to reinvent the wheel. As for sexist... I don't know, never thought about it, but now that I think it I still don't see it

Comment: @Devin the person who told me this said 'Master' refers to male, and 'Mistress' to female... I do think, though, that it's a little bit of an over-sensitive way to look at it, especially, as you seem to imply, apparently 'Master' is used the most... You may want to add it as an answer...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use **master** - if you look at one of the meanings of the word, it seems to cover your situation.

> Also called matrix. an original document, drawing, manuscript, etc., from which copies are made. 
>   [Source](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/master)

This word is also often used in computer science. As for the sexist part - initially I didn't want to comment on this but I decided to - in the system you're referring to an object and not a person, so how can it be sexist? Also, the meaning above (the one you need) is not a meaning of the word mistress and it would be extremely confusing to use it in this context.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not quite what you need, but something that might apply nevertheless would be **baseline** (if the master/original has the role of an authoritative source of truth instead of being accidentally the first issue created).

Comment: I see where you’re coming from, but I think that would be less intuitive for users in my specific use-case, or I’d even say in a “baseline-duplicate” relationship... I’m not a native English speaker (though on it for the last 25+ years), but baseline sounds to me like the ultimate entity that everyone should adhere to, one from which you can derive, and do different, but should preferably do “better”, even... I think it is more referring to quality of content than a relationship between entities, but I mighy be wrong with that...